# prepare statement is not succesful in case of query is having subQuery

Tags: java, jdbc

i am using below simple query to get the result for testing purpose.

```
    qName = "select total_requests from (select 10000 as total_requests from dual)"; //this can be dynamic query
    preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(qName);
    ParameterMetaData pmd = preStatement.getParameterMetaData();

    int stmtCount = pmd.getParameterCount();
    int paramsCount = params == null ? 0 : params.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        if (params[i] != null) {
            preStatement.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
        } else {
            int sqlType = Types.VARCHAR;
            if (!paramValid) {
                try {
                    sqlType = pmd.getParameterType(i + 1);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    paramValid = true;
                }
            }
            preStatement.setNull(i + 1, sqlType);
        }
    }

 ResultSet   rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

once i am executing 3rd line, below error is thrown by application

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.inet.pool.b.getParameterMetaData()Ljava/sql/ParameterMetaData;
        at com.core.admin.util.AnalyzeHelper.fillQuery(AnalyzeHelper.java:61)
```

is this due to subQuery issue?
how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Which JDBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

use this for executing query

```
preStatement.executeQuery();
```

you need to have a result set for viewing

```
ResultSet rs=preStatement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
rs.getString(1);// I assume that first column is a String.If it is an INT then use rs.getInt(1);

//similarly for other columns
}
```

Comment: i added getParameterData to set the parameters in case Query requires. Once i fill the Query , then i am using executeQuery() method only.. but, before executing it self, above expection thrown by app

Comment: @poineer show your full code,point where you are getting exception and write clearly your requirements.It will be easy for us to help you

Comment: @poineer what is pmd?

Comment: it is ParameterMetaData pmd. Apoligizes not specified earlier.

Comment: @poineer I read your code but till now i did not understand your requirement.Post your requirement .

Comment: ;)  My requirement is to pass the Query which can has fully prepared query or we need to fill the query based on inputs. so, i am trying generic query...get the parameter meta data set the values before executing at DB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37721/discussion-between-poineer-and-javabeginner)

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you.

```
qName = "select total_requests from (select 10000 as total_requests from dual)";
preStatement = connection.prepareStatement(qName);
ResultSet rs= preStatement.executeQuery();
```